# Ext.Ajax.request() invokes the failure callback function upon successful request

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm building a PhoneGap - Sencha-touch application for the iOS and Android platforms. I am loading a local .js file using the Ext.Ajax.request() function.

Funny thing happens - the requests succeeds, but the the 'failure' callback is called.
Here is the code:

```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'localfolder/foo.js',
       success : function(xhr){
           // not invoked
       },
       failure : function(response, options){ 
           // response.status == 0
           // wtf, response.responseText contains exactly the contents of the local .js file!
       }
   });
```

Anyone has an Idea why the 'failure' callback is triggered when in fact the request succedded?
[edit]
More importantly, how do I make the 'success' callback to be triggered instead?

Comment: response.status == 0 (I edited the question and added this info)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ext.Ajax simply examines the status code of the underlying XHR (XmlHttpRequest) object it creates.  However, it (incorrectly) assumes that the status is an HTTP status.  As this [Mozilla-provided article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest) discusses, when file: or ftp: schemes are used, a status value of 0 indicates success.

You can modify the onComplete function in Ext.data.Connection (in src/data/Connection.js) to look at the scheme of the URL, and decide if it should use an HTTP-based status or a "0=OK" status to determine success.

It is perfectly legal for non-success results to have a body that can be used by the client.  This is why your response.responseText still shows up correctly.

Comment: Thanks @mmigdol, I did not know about the different success codes for http:, file: or ftp:.  

I did manage to override the 'failure' function by indeed specifying an onComplete function. But I'm looking for a way to cause the 'success' function to be called, just to make my code a bit more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

I usually using response like this, maybe it'll help

```
{
  success:true, // success status
  data: [] // data from process
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am loading a local .js file, how am I supposed to add the json object to the response? the response is the entire content of my local .js file

Comment: replace the [] with xhr so it'll like {
  success:true,data: xhr
}